# Where did the slang phrase "manda ver!" originate?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia, girias

> - ["manda ver!"](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/manda+ver/) - definition - "expressão usada para estimular alguém a realizar uma ação ou dizer que ela já está apta a realizar a ação." (phrase used to encourage someone to do something or to mean that they are able to do it.)
>
> examples:
>
> - Aproveita que hoje é feriado e manda ver uma cerveja para nós!
> - A - Acho que vou tirar uma soneca.  B - Vai lá, manda ver.
> - A - Ah, eu vou é exigir os meus direitos.  B - Isso, garoto, manda ver.

"manda ver" is current usage among teenagers in Rio de Janeiro and I presume it is a relatively new acquisition because I don't remember having heard it before the year 2000. When and where exactly did it originate?  Has it crossed the Atlantic yet?

Comment: Não conheço. Deve ser coisa que só o pessoal que via a Malhação há de reconhecer.

Comment: @Artefacto  O teu background é de ptBR ou ptPT?

Comment: Sou de Lisboa. (15 caracteres)

Comment: Não se usa em Portugal, que eu saiba.

Comment: Mandar ver existe em São Paulo desde que eu me entendo por gente (ou seja, há mais de 20 anos pelo menos).

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim  I'm a senior citizen and that may be why you first heard it long before me.

Comment: What about "manda brasa"? Isn't it from the 70's?

Comment: @bfavaretto  Yes, I remember that from my teenage days.

Comment: "Manda Ver" é uma expressão muito usada em apresentações artísticas. Geralmente em filmes sobre música ou dança alguém vai dizer "manda ver!" para encorajar quem vai se apresentar. Também vamos encontrar esse uso após uma tomada de decisão em que alguém diz "manda var nisso aí!" (está decidido, faça isso!)

Comment: Assim como *manda bronca!* *manda bala!* e *mete bronca!*

Comment: Falado muito em São Paulo, [letra](http://www.letras10.com) usada bastante.

Comment: Centaurus, should the first example be "manda vir"? In Portugal, it would... (but we don't have the expression "manda ver".)

Comment: @ANeves   "manda ver" is a set phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encontro a expressão no prefácio de Luiz Travassos, escrito em 1981, ao livro de Marcelo Rubens Paiva, "[Feliz Ano Velho](http://static.recantodasletras.com.br/arquivos/5319053.pdf)":

> Ou então desencana e **manda ver** no teu texto.

Deve ser portanto pelo menos um pouco mais antiga do que isso: o Travassos provavelmente tinha uma boa dose de certeza de que seria entendido ao escrever o prefácio.

Encontro "mandou ver" num artigo ainda mais antigo de Plínio Marcos publicado na [Folha de São Paulo](http://almanaque.folha.uol.com.br/plinio_marcos_o_carnaval_dos_cordoes.htm) em 1977:

> Mais encantado ainda ficou o Feijó quando aquela mulata pegou no surdo
>   e **mandou ver**.

Comment: Bom trabalho de pesquisa.  Fiquei surpreso de a expressão ser tão antiga.  Não me recordo de tê-la ouvido quando jovem.

Answer (score 0):

In my childhood in the northeast (1950s) of Brasil, it was used to say  "Manda vara!" meaning "screw it" or "fuck it".
The term "vara" is also used to name men's sexual organ.
As it was considered very outrageous,  boys use to say an "abbreviation" as "Manda v". As I kind of "code" to use among girls, ladies an adults in general, with many different meanings, as "get this done", "do it" etc.

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese SE! Interesting statement, but it would be great if you could provide some evidence to support it.